# Is it possible with Envers to have different audit modes for different concrete derived classes with a common a mapped baseclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have two JPA entities with the same fields, which I want to store in different tables. So I have based them on an abstract common mapped base class to avoid doubling code. Now I want one of these table to be audited, and the other one not. But when I set the one class to audited, Envers creates an _AUD table for both of the derived classes.
Even setting the other derived class to audit mode NotAudited, its audit table is created.
Is there a possibility to configure it as described?

My (simplified) classes:

```
@MappedBaseClass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractPrice {
    // some fields and some methods
}

@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode=RelationTargetAuditMode.AUDITED)
public class Price extends AbstractPrice {
}

@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode=RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
public class OriginalPrice extends AbstractPrice {
}
```

Comment: Your `AbstractPrice` isn't an entity it should be a `MappedSuperClass` .

Comment: Thanks; I have corrected that. But part of the problem stays on: when I set one of the derived classes to Audited, the other gets audited, too, even if I forbid it.

Comment: The `targetAuditMode` should be used only for fields which a relations. If you don't want an entity to be audited, simply remove the annotation. Do you still have audit tables both for `Price` and `OriginalPrice` when you have only one annotation? Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: @adamw: Thanks, that solved the problem. I did not find any mentioning of the fact, that audit modes are only for fields. When I remove the annotation completely, the _aud table is not created any more. Do you want to state this as answer, that I may accept it?

Comment: Great to hear that it works - added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `targetAuditMode` should be used only for fields which are relations. If you don't want an entity to be audited, simply remove the annotation.